# Returning values from Promise(Bluebird) in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, restify, bluebird

I am learning Node.js and was looking at the Promise module. I am very new at this so please bare with bad code conventions and stuff. I am trying to build a REST Client API using restify. I have attached my Client Code below:

Here is my Client:

```
// local functions
function loadResult(err, req, res, obj) {
    //console.log(err, req, res, obj);
    var result = {
        'err': err,
        'text': obj
    };
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}

function getClient() {
    if (client) {
        return client;
    } else {
        client = restify.createJsonClient(options);
        return client;
    }
};

function RestClient(headers) {

    if (headers) {
        global_headers.Authorization = headers.Authorization || global_headers.Authorization;
        options.headers = global_headers;
    }
};

RestClient.prototype.getClient = getClient;

RestClient.prototype.doGET = function doGET(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        client.get(path, loadResult);
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log("before final return:" + result);
        return result;
    });
};

// exports
module.exports = RestClient;
```

In the console when I run the following lines:

```
var Rest = require('./testRest.js');
var restClient = new Rest();
var client = restClient.getClient();
var data = restClient.doGET('/hello/mark');
```

I can see the result printed just once on the console. But the Data is just what I believe a Promise. Is there a way for me to get the result in data? Also trying to figure out why the result never got printed the second time.

P.S.: I tried using Promise.promisifyAll(require('restify')) but it kept throwing some error saying fn is not a function which force use Promise in this way.

Comment: It seems you have to learn how to work with promises: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @FelixKling You are correct. I am a beginner to Javascript and Promises and still trying to get my head around it. So any help is appreciated. fyi, I still don't get what I am doing wrong

Comment: @Darshan you are not resolving the promise, see the `resolve` parameter you define? You are never calling it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no such error when I do:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("restify"));
```

Secondly, restify unfortunately uses some weird getters when exporting the module, as getters can (and do) have side effects, promisifyAll will not visit them, so the one line magic won't work. You need to promisify the classes manually, e.g.

```
Promise.promisifyAll(require("restify").JsonClient.prototype);
```

Then you would call:

```
   client.getAsync(path).spread(function(req, res, obj) {

   });
```

Comment: Thanks @Esailija, that was a great  trick. But it reduces my ability to use custom headers. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @Darshan how does it reduce your ability to use custom headers?

Comment: Sorry if it sounds dumb but if I do
`var json = Promise.promisifyAll(require("restify").JsonClient.prototype);`
I end up with a client object. I cannot initialize it. when I try to do this I end up getting an error 
`var client = json()
TypeError: Property 'json' of object #<Object> is not a function
    at repl:1:14`
and the api that i have does not have any setter for custom headers/options

Comment: @Darshan The promisification is done as side effect on the class, it doesn't have useful result here.... don't save the result of PromisifyAll anywhere, just make sure it has been called once in your application in somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Esailija. I got it wrong the first time :). Your trick really helped!

Comment: @Darshan: if you need to use custom header you still can do it as getAsync (as well as his original counterpart get) expecting first parameter to be a string (path) or object ({path: "/path", headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}}), so you are not limited in any way.