# Simple bluebird example with restify doesn't work

Tags: promise, bluebird

taking straight from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27810135/889053):

This code never executes.

```
  var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("restify"));
var restify = require("restify");

var http = require('http');

const PORT=7070;


function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});


var client = restify.createJsonClientAsync({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7070'
});

client.get("/foo").spread(function(req, res, obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

I only put together this simple example to prove it to myself after my production code didn't work. I can hit localhost:7070 with curl and I get the expected results.

In a nutshell: I need to execute 3 GET calls to a server before I can create a POST and hence my need for promises.

Anyone can shed some insight? I can't imagine this being simpler.

Comment: There should be an error, don't you get any?

Comment: Creating the client should be synchronous. Getting the path response should be asynchronous.

Comment: I don't think you should promisify restify. You can promisify the code inside the handler or you can chain the handlers and call next on each to move to the next handler

Comment: @vbanden can you offer an example as an answer? I think I know what you mean

Comment: I can but I would need to know more about what you are actually trying to accomplish. If I don't answer your exact question I will get all the eager down voters

Comment: updated my answer with a working promisified restify client.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Apparently i did not read the question correctly, here is a working example of 2 gets using a promisified restify json client. you would just do another spread in the body of the second spread for your post.

```
var promise = require('bluebird');
var restify = require('restify');
promise.promisifyAll(restify.JsonClient.prototype);
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080',
    version: '*'
});


client.getAsync('/api/resource/1').spread(function(req, res, obj) {
    console.log('result 1', obj);

    return client.getAsync('/api/resource/2').spread(function(req, res, obj) {
        console.log('result 2', obj);
    });
});
```

As I stated in my comments, I would not promisify restify itself. Instead I would use either a handler whose body executes promise code or a chain of handlers (which can also have promises in the body). restify should only receive the request and execute the handler.

I will use modified versions of the basic example from the restify page to illustrate each.

**Promise in the message body using knex.js which returns a promise**

```
var knex = require('knex')(connectionConfig);
var restify = require('restify');

function promisePost(req, res, next) {
    // get 1
    knex.select('*')
    .from('table1')
    .where('id', '=', req.body.table1_id)
    .then(function(result1) {
        // get 2
        return knex.select('*')
        .from('table2')
        .where('id', '=', req.body.table2_id)
        .then(function(result2) {
            return knex('table3').insert({
                table1_value: result1.value,
                table2_value: result2.value
            })
            .then(function(result3) {
                res.send(result3);
                return next();
            });
        });
    });
}

var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.post('/myroute', promisePost);

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

**now with chained handlers**

```
var knex = require('knex')(connectionConfig);
var restify = require('restify');

function get1(req, res, next) {
    knex.select('*').from('table1')
    .where('id', '=', req.body.table1_id)
    .then(function(result1) {
        res.locals.result1 = result1;
        return next();
    });
}
function get2(req, res, next) {
    knex.select('*').from('table2')
    .where('id', '=', req.body.table2_id)
    .then(function(result2) {
        res.locals.result2 = result2;
        return next();
    });
}

function post(req, res, next) {
    knex('table3').insert({
        table1_value: res.locals.result1,
        table2_value: res.locals.result2
    })
    .then(function(result3) {
        res.send(result3);
        return next();
    });
}

var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.post('/myroute', get1, get2, post);

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Comment: I suspected that's what you meant. I can see that my origin question wasn't clear that it was the client that needed promising. But, your example about the server does give me some ideas. Thanks